# Could some Red and Blue shifts be the result of light passing through "dark matter"?

Tags: cosmology, visible-light, speed-of-light, space-expansion, dark-matter

As i see it, light behaves in certain ways, as the Double Slit experiement shows,
So when light comes into contact with dark matter, it becomes both a wave and a particle, the wave is bent around the dark matter, which we see as gravitational lensing,
but the particle will go through the dark matter, but will also leave our frame of reference, 
follow the particle through dark matter and its speed would not change staying at $c$, but only relative to the the space it travels through, 
it would eventually pass through dark matter, we would see this first as a red or blue shift as it slowly emerges (from our perspective), and continues on it way,
Never knowing it had passed through any medium,
where as the wave had passed around the dark matter thousands, millions, or billions of years before, depending upon the mass of the dark matter.

Comment: This isn't the way light behaves. There isn't a wave and a particle that follow separate paths.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This seems to be assuming dark matter in order to disprove the Doppler shift. Confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Light interacts with dark matter only through gravitation. That is why we try to map dark matter distribution in the universe by statistically studying the small distortions in the images of background galaxies (weak lensing regime).

Whole redshift-sliced 3D maps of dark matter have been traced for some small regions of the sky, by means of weak lensing distortion. In all cases, the observed properties of the background objects are in a statistical sense the same (apart from shape distortion) for objects observed through, and not through, dark matter clumps.

That is one of the proofs for dark matter not interacting with photons.

Another proof is in the strong lensing regime of multiple lensed quasars. The Hubble parameter can be derived by measuring time delays between flux changes of a background quasar, as detected in two lensed images. That time delays happen because the photons travel through different paths, both through the dark matter halo of the lens galaxy and the Universe. But the measured line waveleght redshifts agree perfectly with the optical paths derived from the geometry of the lens, and no additional frequency shift has ever been observed. As expected from GR, photons leaving a dark matter clump behind recover the colour they had when they entered it.

That is, dark matter affects light only by means of the metric tensor, but doesn't interact with the photons. Otherwise it would had been already observed.

Comment: After reading your question again, I definitively don't know what your question is...

Comment: I can see its a waste of time in this forum, no one can think for themselves, and do not even understand how light can be a particle and wave and both these interactions with dark matter, yes you all seem to only understand the wave that we see by gravitational lensing, that bends around these gravitational masses.lets hope the next generation will have more foresight, and get physics going again.

Comment: Come on @MarkEmery, Eduardo has given you quite a nice answer (+1), even though reading your question it is hard to guess what you are up to.

Comment: Yes you are right it is a "good" answer, but where it is stated that dark matter does not ineract with the photons otherwise it would already be observed is what i do not agree with, we do not observe because it enters a different space-time (twin paradox), so we will observe it evenually, in varying densities of dark matter, when it finally makes it through.like light going through "water", do not take water literally. even when light travels through diamond it is slowed down, dark matter is folded space.

Comment: @Mark Emery, dark matter is as "folded space" as normal matter, and that is why we observe different images of the same background quasar when a galactic dark matter halo happens to be in the line of sight. The phenomenon is studied with real data since 1979 with the discovery of the first lensed quasar Q0957+561. Dark matter DOES slow down the photons as you well say, but that is indeed the way all lenses work (glass lenses too). You are right, but there is no othe way we could be observing lensed images...

Comment: And for the images to reach us, the photons must have already crossed the halos. Otherwise we wouldn`t see the background images at all! And there is no statistical differences in surface flux or redshift between images that reach us after travelling across dark matter and the others. That is, there is lot of empirical evidence of photons having crossed dark matter and not have suffered any scattering or interaction further than the gravitational deflection. It is not dogma, but just overwhelming empirical evidence.

Comment: The magnification of lensed images is a consequence of their bigger apparent size, but mean surface flux is unchanged, as well as the frequency of the light. Dark matter has no cross-section for photons, or even for baryonic matter, it is collisionless and only produces curvature. That is why many still are searching for alternative gravity theories. Because there is observational evidences far beyond any doubt, that photons do cross dark matter and do reach us unscattered.

Comment: Dark matter could have had received another name like "misterious curvature", but there was at the beginning probably a prejudice, people hoped it would be detected soon as massive compact objects or any kind of new partice... Now, there is a minoritary but serious tendence of people trying to explain it as a new theory of gravity. Imho, a name like "additional curvature" would fit better than dark matter, since is less prone to prejudices about its nature.

Comment: (and forgive my first comment, but I really couldn`t understand what you were asking, not until I read some comments you posted later)

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, and sorry, it is not always easy to get across what we mean , so thank you for your patience, this is because i was trying to understand if light speed is constant between galaxies, and as 80/90% of our universe is still dark matter, whether with all this gravitational lenseing, Is anything where we think it is. And depending how long (a split photon) as been travelling through dark matter, would we first see the "wave" with gravitational lensing(distorted galaxies), then later see the particle(non distorted galaxies)?

Comment: Have there been any lensed galaxies, that are simialar to galaxies between us and this lensing?

Comment: Sounds like you might find a better answer on http://www.timecube.com/ That guy is an expert at "outside the box" physics. On this site we generally focus on real physics.

Comment: If dark matter is anti matter, matter and light would be pushed away, 
but also light(photons) are in effect there own anti particle, which would mean when a photon comes into contact with dark matter it would be both a photon and an anti photon, the photon would be pushed away in the opposite direction and the anti-photon which would then pass through dark matter.

Answer (score 3):

This is another version of the ["tired light" hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light).  This doesn't work for a variety of reasons, among which are the facts that there are no absorption or emission peaks evident in light, there is no blurring of the light from distant objects (stars look like points, not globs), and there appears to be no dependence on the angular view from the sky when looking for redshifts (while dark matter DOES appear to be clumped).

Comment: light passing through dark matter would be similar to light passing through fiber optics, there is no reason for "blurring",dark matter is folded space, which would from our perspective focus light into a very narrow beam.

Comment: @MarkEmery: scattering is scattering.  And fiber optics certainly do blur the light--the index of refraction depends on the wavelength of the light passing through it.  If the interaction with dark matter is independent of wavelength, then it would be quite unique.

Comment: As you say scattering is scattering, and there is no blurring of light from distant objects, but there should be,it is dark matter that refocuses these objects.

Comment: @MarkEmery: what?  Are you talking about gravitational lensing?  That is one of the few effects that is NOT frequency-dependent (so long as the frequency of the light is much less than the curvature of the relevant region of space).  If you have light bouncing off of/through dark matter, you have to explain why there is no dispersion of the light--i.e., answer why is the DM/matter interaction frequency-independent.

Comment: Our universe is thought to be made of 85% dark matter, plus galaxy clusters, alot of gravitational lensing going on, but still we see "no blurring" from distant objects,what we are really seeing is the photon particle that as travelled through the D/M, which as not scattered, the wave that went around the dark matter has G/L as been lost in the maze of D/M, we only see the odd effect that as not yet been completely distorted, Once the photon leaves D/M it continues as a wave and a particle.but each time on coming in contact with D/M, the photon wave goes around, and the particle goes through.

Comment: @MarkEmery: what?  what is G/L?  And moving around through a maze is scattering.  And why is your proposed interaction with dark matter wavelength independent?  A collapse of a wave function would almost certainly not be.

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter--as the term is understood--does not interact electromagnetically.
Light only interacts electromagnetically.

So, no it could not.

Comment: Sorry we do not yet fully understand Dark matter, you are only stateing speculation yourself. "So,no it could not", is what i expect from one with no ability to see other than what they are told. Not long ago it was thought that light could not be a wave and a particle, but we move on.

Comment: This question is for those who can think outside the box,

Comment: I'm not speculating. Dark matter is *known* to not interact electromagnetically because if it did we would be able to *see* it. Essentially nothing *else* is known about the stuff, but that is an observational fact.

Comment: We can not see it, because once the particle enters dark matter it leaves "our space time", dark matter is higher dimensional, even though the "particle" would still be travelling at c within this medium,

Comment: We do not see light interaction as the wave travels around dark matter, but the particle enters dark matter, but from our reference point nothing would be noticed as space time within is different to our space time, inside a billion light years would be like a light year to us. from our viewpoint the particle would have stop, even though it was still travelling at c inside dark matter. but it eventually will get through this we would see as red or blue  shift,as light would be stretched out within, so before it catches up on re-entering our space time we would see this shift.

Comment: Light interacts gravitationally too, as is explained in the other answer.